# Mesh auto smoothing and vertex subdivision causing triangle artifacting

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model a plane in blender, but am seeing these strange triangular artifacts around the cockpit:
[image]
[image]

I believe this is happening because of the auto smoothing and this vertex subdivision:
[image]

I have tried many things to fix: marking the edges sharp, ripping the vertices apart, deleting all the vertices and letting blender triangulate the polygons itself, etc. No matter what I do it doesn't seem to help. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ngons are causing these artefacts, maybe use less vertices, begin with a 16 vertex cylinder:

[image]

Cut the half, give it a *Mirror* modifier, draw the shape of the cockpit with the knife tool:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth, correct the topology:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @moonbots :-) This helped a lot. I really appreciate it, thanks so much!